# Method load() defines Objective-C class method 'load', which is not permitted by Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and I'm creating a PFObject subclass conforming to the protocol PFSubclassing! 
It was working all fine, but now I'm using Swift 1.2 and it gives me this error:

```
1. override class func load() {
2.      self.registerSubclass()
3. }
```

On line 1: Method 'load()' defines Objective-C class method 'load', which is not permitted by Swift 1.2

Anyone have this problem yet? How can I fix?

Comment: You are really saying `function` instead of `func`? Is this some kind of Parse thing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an NSHispster article about method swizzling that touches on this in different context:

> Unfortunately, a load class method implemented in Swift is never
>   called by the runtime, rendering that recommendation an impossibility.
>   Instead, we're left to pick among second-choice options:
>
> - **Implement method swizzling in initialize.** This can be done safely, so long as you check the type at execution time and wrap the swizzling in
>     dispatch_once (which you should be doing anyway).
> - **Implement method swizzling in the app delegate.** Instead of adding method swizzling via a class extension, simply add a method to the app
>     delegate to be executed when
>     application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is called. Depending on
>     the classes you're modifying, this may be sufficient and should
>     guarantee your code is executed every time.

Link: http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/

-

More info form dev forums:

> Swift 1.1 allowed you to define "+load" methods with "class func
>   load()", but they were not actually run at startup time of your app
>   like Objective-C +load methods are.  Swift 1.2 bans them to avoid the
>   impression that this might work.

Link: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1102025#1102025

-

tl;dr `initialize()` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` seem to be decent places for such things in Swift.

Comment: The most complete answer, so I marked as official answer! Thanks man!

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

```
override class func initialize() {
   var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
      self.registerSubclass()
   }
}
```

The Parse documentation has been updated : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclassing-pfobject

Answer (score 7):

I'm calling `registerSubclass()` method in AppDelegate before `Parse.setApplicationId` for every subclass of `PFObject` and it works.

Answer (score 7):

Overriding `load()` *never* worked with Swift. Earier it was simply not called. I filed a bug for Apple back then (Bug ID 18423731), and recently I got a response that the issue has been addressed by explicitly informing the developer that this is not allowed in Swift.

```
extension UIButton {
    // !! never called
    override public class func load() { // Method 'load()' defines Objective-C class method 'load', which is not permitted by Swift 1.2
        super.load()
        println("not called earlier anyway");
    }
}
```

So.... don't. Even if the documentation says otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working by replacing it with:

```
override class func initialize() {
}
```

Comment: Note that `+load` and `+initialize` are different. `+load` runs at the time the binary is loaded, regardless of whether the class is used; and you can have multiple `+load` methods -- one in each category in addition to the main one -- all without interfering with each other (normally category methods replace existing methods with the same name). `+initialize`, on the other hand, runs lazily when the class is messaged for the first time.

Comment: @newacct Do you know the equivalent of load() In Swift? For now I'm leaving the comment above as the answer because it solve my problem for now