# Method swizzling in Swift 3.1

Tags: swift

Now that in Xcode (8.3b3), using Swift 3.1, there’s a new compiler warning saying that the method `initialize()` will be disallowed in future versions, there is an alternative for method swizzling?

Comment: You could write the swizzling code in Objective-C?

Comment: You can still swizzle in Swift, but Swift offers no way to execute code automatically, when a class is loaded. So you have to initiate the swizzling explicitly, somewhere (unless you  mix with Objective-C as matt suggested).

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422468/method-load-defines-objective-c-class-method-load-which-is-not-permitted-by.

Answer (score 0):

> Implement method swizzling in the app delegate Instead of adding
>   method swizzling via a class extension, simply add a method to the app
>   delegate to be executed when
>   application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is called. Depending on
>   the classes you’re modifying, this may be sufficient and should
>   guarantee your code is executed every time.

Source: [NsHipster](http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/)

Comment: This approach won't work for classes initialized during an Application Extension execution context, as `AppDelegate`'s methods are not called in this case.